# Parsing Text File using array and Sed and Awk in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed, xargs

I have what appears to me a complex text file that include around 300 entries.
I have no idea how  to go about parsing this file to get the output I want.
Each of my network users has an entry in the file. So in the text file, each **user** name starts with:

```
USER:martha
USER:Othello
USER:darwin
```

Underneath each **user** entry in the file there are a host of information I require , but one user can have one entry and another can have multiple entries. Here is the example of 3 such entries

```
USER:martha
    POSITION: 170.198.82.13 [VLT(304394),PT(FULL)]
            CLIENT: jcrm19.1.p2ps -258-
            ACCESSPOINT: 170.198.82.13/net
            APPLICATION: 91

USER:othello 
    POSITION: 170.198.80.212 [VLT(307571),PT(FULL)]
            CLIENT: jcrm15.1.p2ps -258-
            ACCESSPOINT: 170.198.80.212/net
            APPLICATION: 256

            CLIENT: jcrm15.1.p2ps -258-
            ACCESSPOINT: 170.198.80.212/net
            APPLICATION: 256

    POSITION: 170.198.80.209 [VLT(306561),PT(FULL)]
            CLIENT: jcrm14.1.p2ps -258-
            ACCESSPOINT: 170.198.80.209/net
            APPLICATION: 256

            CLIENT: pwrm14.1.p2ps -258-
            ACCESSPOINT: 170.198.80.209/net
            APPLICATION: 256

            CLIENT: pwrm14.1.p2ps -258-
            ACCESSPOINT: 170.198.80.209/net
            APPLICATION: 256


USER:darwin
    POSITION: 170.198.19.102 [VLT(297987),PT(FULL)]
            CLIENT: jcrm16.1.p2ps -258-
            ACCESSPOINT: 170.198.19.102/net
            APPLICATION: 91
```

The final output should look as follow:

```
USER        Position           Client     Application 

Martha      170.198.82.13       jcrm19      91
Othello     170.198.80.212      jcrm15      256
Othello     170.198.80.209      jcrm14      256
Martin      170.198.19.102      jcrm16      91
```

I have some experience with arrays and I could grep out some of the information and assign to variable and print them. But I just don't know how to read the information into the arrays as the entries under each **"USER"** since they are of different length and content.

So How do I read **USER: martha** and then jump to **user:othello** ? Also, under **user:othello** there are two **"Positions"** that I need to grab. I just don't know how to put the content I'm looking for into array variables or regular variables. I never had to parse a file that had different length and content data for each use. Not sure how many lines I have to read before I start reading and assigning values to array or values for the next user> Can you provide some hints or perhaps a piece of code that I can start with ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got my Mac to hand so this is untested...

```
awk -F: '/^USER:/{u=$2} /POSITION:/{p=$2} /CLIENT:/{c=$2} /APPLICATION:/{print u,p,c,$2}' yourfile
```

Comment: OP just wants to pick the block with `POSITION`, yours prints entry for each block

Comment: @Kent Oh, yes, you are right, thank you. I'll leave him to choose between your and anubhava's answers.

Comment: Hi Mark. I tried your one liner and worked great. Not sure how it works , but it works. So thank you. I really have to understand how this position stuff work. also when I ran it against my original log file, it produced an additional columns of data .. but that's fine./

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` with `column`:

```
awk -F '[: ]+' 'BEGIN{print "USER", "Position", "Client", "Application"} 
  $1=="USER"{u=$2} $2=="POSITION"{p=$3}$2=="CLIENT"{c=$3}
  $2=="APPLICATION"&&p{print u, p, c, $3; p=""}' file | column -t

USER     Position        Client         Application
martha   170.198.82.13   jcrm19.1.p2ps  91
othello  170.198.80.212  jcrm15.1.p2ps  256
othello  170.198.80.209  jcrm14.1.p2ps  256
darwin   170.198.19.102  jcrm16.1.p2ps  91
```

Comment: This assumes that the fields will always be in the order in the sample. Which may be correct but should be pointed out.

Comment: hi thx .. I tried this. Yes the fields are always in this order. It works with the sample I provided and not with the text file I have .. Not sure why . I have to look at the log file again. Thx for quick response. will have to look later as I have to run to catch a train thx again!! anubhava

Comment: Sure let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS="" -F'[:\n ]*' '/^USER/{u=$2}
 /POSI/{p=/^USER/?$4:$3
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
     if($i=="CLIENT"){sub(/\..*/,"",$(i+1))
                      print u,p,$(i+1),$NF;break}}' file
```

the output without header:

```
martha 170.198.82.13 jcrm19 91
othello 170.198.80.212 jcrm15 256
othello 170.198.80.209 jcrm14 256
darwin 170.198.19.102 jcrm16 91
```

you could add header and pipe to `column -t` to gain better format

Comment: Hi Kent. Thanks for reply. Sorry I never got around this post. I tried ur code and it does not do anything. It produces no error and it does not produces any output?